# Spring security - logout 404

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Аfter successful authorization I press the logout button. Logout is successful, it redirects me to the login page, but when I try to login again, I get a 404 error - The requested resource [/logout] is not available.
I've read popular issues with this problem, but nothing worked for me.
My logout form:

```
<li class="header__user-menu-item">
                 <spring:url value="/logout" var="logout"/>
                 <form:form id="form" action="${logout}" method="post">
                    <a class="header__user-menu-link"  title="Logout" data-logout>
                        <svg class="header__user-menu-icon" width="22" height="20">
                            <use xlink:href="#logout"></use>
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                    </form:form>
                    <iframe id="jrLogoutFrame" scrolling="no" width="0" height="0" style="opacity:0; position:absolute; top: -100000px"></iframe>
                </li>
```

Login form:

```
<spring:url value="/login" var="login"/>
                <form:form id="form" action="${login}" method="post" class="auth__form">
                    <label class="auth__form-item">
                        <svg class="auth__form-image" width="15" height="16">
                            <use xlink:href="#man"></use>
                        </svg>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="auth__form-input" autocomplete="off"
                               placeholder="Login" required="" autofocus="">
                    </label>
                    <label class="auth__form-item">
                        <svg class="auth__form-image" width="15" height="17">
                            <use xlink:href="#lock"></use>
                        </svg>
                        <input tabindex="0" type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" class="auth__form-input" autocomplete="off"
                               placeholder="Password"/>"  required="">
                    </label>

                    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                        <div class="auth__error">
                            <svg class="auth__error-icon" width="18" height="18">
                                <use xlink:href="#warning"></use>
                            </svg>
                            <p class="auth__error-message">
                                
                        <c:if test="${error eq 'app.login.locked.for.time.error'}">
                            <spring:message javaScriptEscape="true"
                                            code="app.login.locked.for.time.error"
                                            arguments="${timeLock}" htmlEscape="false"/>
                        </c:if>
                        <c:if test="${error != 'app.login.locked.for.time.error'}">
                                <fmt:message key="${error}"/>
                        </c:if>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </c:if>
                    <button class="auth__form-button" type="submit" name="send-data" onclick="disableButton(this)">Login</button>
                </form:form>
```

security.xml:

```
<beans profile="ldaps">
      
        <sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

        <sec:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>

        <bean id="loginSuccessHandler" class="xxx.CustomLoginSuccessHandler"/>
        <bean id="loginFailedHandler" class="xxx.CustomLoginFailedHandler"/>

        <bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="xxx.CustomLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
        <bean id="AdUsersAuthenticationProvider" class="xxx.AdUsersAuthenticationProvider"/>
        <bean id="RsaAuthenticationProvider" class="xxx.RsaAuthenticationProvider"/>

        <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
            <constructor-arg>
                <list>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter"/>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>
                    <bean class="xxx.DatabaseRoleVoter"/>
                </list>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>

        <sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/test-alive/*permitted/**" access="permitAll"/>
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/pinChanged" access="permitAll"/>
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/changePassword" access="permitAll"/>
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

            <sec:form-login login-page="/login" authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler"
                            authentication-failure-handler-ref="loginFailedHandler"
                            authentication-details-source-ref="rsaDetailsSource"
            />


            <sec:logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"/>
            
            <sec:csrf disabled="true"/>
            <sec:session-management>
                <sec:concurrency-control session-registry-ref="sessionRegistry"/>
            </sec:session-management>
            <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/access-denied"/>
        </sec:http>

        <bean class="xxx.PasswordUtil" id="passwordEncoder" factory-method="getPasswordEncoder"/>

        <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
                <sec:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
            </sec:authentication-provider>
            <sec:authentication-provider ref="tmonLdapProvider"/>
            <sec:authentication-provider ref="RsaAuthenticationProvider"/>
            <sec:authentication-provider ref="AdUsersAuthenticationProvider"/>
        </sec:authentication-manager>
    </beans>
```

Comment: When you try to login, which url are you sending request?

Comment: I can only guess because you need to send login form as well

Comment: When i try to login after logout, i get http://localhost:8080/logout GET- 404 on console. Does this mean that after re-login, I am redirected to a wrong link?

Comment: Most probably you are posting form to wrong link
I think GET operation fails so it means you are sending request to get Logout page but it does not exist

Comment: You can redirect to logout page then user can go to login page

Answer (score 0):

This is because the default processor of/logout sent a response to redirect to the login page, and the default login page does not exist (or has not been configured), so 404 occurs.